# Exclude Data from Results

Tags: python

I am new to python so bear with me. Through the documentation I have read I should be able to omit any line of data for "mac" that contains the word None. However I am not getting back my expect results. Did I write my loop wrong?

```
for data in resp_Data:
    if data["mac"] == "None":
        continue
    else:
        print data["node_id"]
        print data["id"]
        print data["display_name"]
        print data["mac"]
        print "\n"
```

Thanks!

Comment: show a sample value for `resp_Data` that goes wrong. Furthermore, what is the expected result?

Comment: What is the value of `resp_Data`?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `if "None" in data["mac"]` instead.

Comment: 51
21999
VMware 8E0EDB
None -#Get rid of this.

Comment: When you do 
"for data in resp_Data: print data", what gets printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments in other answers you seem to be dealing with a NoneType not a string "None". And you do not need an else statement if you are going to ignore doing anything with the result if there is no Mac

```
for data in resp_Data:
    if data["Mac"] is not None:
        print data["node_id"]
        print data["id"]
        print data["display_name"]
        print data["mac"]
        print "\n"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and now I have a better understanding of the logic. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not checking equality here and you need to see if "None" is a `substring` of data['mac']

you may use  `"None" in data['mac']` instead of `data['mac'] == None`

**Code**

```
for data in resp_Data:
    if  "None" in data["mac"]:
        continue
    else:
        print data["node_id"]
        print data["id"]
        print data["display_name"]
        print data["mac"]
        print "\n"
```

Comment: I tried that, am I supposed to have two if statements?

Comment: @SenorInIssaquah that was a typo reoved it

Comment: I tried that and got --TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Comment: Then your resp_Data  is not an array of dictionaries , can you please print the data before if statements to check ad validate its structure

Comment: its JSON resp_str = item.read().decode('utf-8')
resp_Data = json.loads(resp_str)

Comment: ie, it could be an array or a single  object.  The code you have given assumes resp_Data  is an array of dictionary. could you please print resp_Data before loop and check that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing to see if `data['mac']` is *equal to* `"None"`, not if it *contains* it.

Comment: I actually have the word None there. and i want to omit that.

Comment: Please avoid making edits that put words in the answers mouth, @Marein. If you'd like to suggest that improvement in the comments, then feel free. But let the OP deiced first whether or not they would like to include it in their answer.